# Java NumberFormatException while converting 1000000000000001 to base 5

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert the String "1000000000000001" to base 5 using Java:

`Integer number = Integer.parseInt("1000000000000001", 5);`

However, I am gettig NumberFormatException. The string is trimmed and only contains 1 and 0. Could someone please explain why am I getting this exception?

Comment: @Tunaki - Makes sense, actually the string is "1000000000000001" and all that I am trying to do is to find the representation of this string in base 5. Would I be able to do that?

Comment: No, it is too big for an `int`. Visual exercise: try your code with a radix of 2, then 3, then 4 and compare the results. When you reach 5, you'll understand why it breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number `1000000000000001` in base 5 is equivalent to the number `30517578126` in base 10 (you can verify this yourself or use [online tools](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/base_convert/)).

However, `30,517,578,126` is too big to fit in an `int` value. The maximal value, [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is `2,147,483,647`. This explains the exception you are getting - from [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-):

> throws `NumberFormatException` - if the String does not contain a parsable `int`.

which is the case here.

You need to use a `long`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = Long.parseLong("1000000000000001", 5);
    System.out.println(number); // prints "30517578126"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BigInteger(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-) like

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("1000000000000001", 5));
```

Output is

```
30517578126
```

**Note**: That [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 **or** `2147483647`.